# Why can't I log into my dropbear VirtualBox with ssh? "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" or "Permission denied"

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant, dropbear

I have a router set up in VirtualBox. I can access it from the console, but it doesn't have a scroll buffer and I can't select with the mouse. I'm trying to ssh into it as root. It uses dropbear.

Output from `ssh root@192.168.1.1 -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no` below:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.1 -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Chloe/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Chloe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/Chloe/.ssh/known_hosts:69
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4152/8192
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:NbAuswB0VwGSup8zY59jN2Alouq1Kl37PiEENXhAuPU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Chloe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/Chloe/.ssh/known_hosts:69
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.1
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Chloe/.ssh/known_hosts:69
debug2: bits set: 4116/8192
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_rsa (0x80059a48)
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug2: key: /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.1.1's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.1's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.1's password:
```

`Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.1"
```

`vagrant up`

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
    default: Adapter 3: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
```

I did verify the root password was correct.

[image: verify root password with manual hash]

When I try to login via the NAT adapter created by Vagrant:

```
$ ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

There are no `sshd` or `dropbear` logs in `/var/logs`.

I tried to run dropbear and log output, but it didn't output anything.

[image: dropbear]

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.1 -p 22
root@192.168.1.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

This is `iptables --list`

[image: iptables]
[image: iptables]
[image: iptables]
[image: iptables]

I killed my local Cygwin SSHD and now I get `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Connection refused` even though my host computer has a 10.0.0.* IP address! So I'm left with accessing with `root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` which gives an error.

I deleted 2 iptable rules but it didn't help. Same ssh_exchange_identification" error.

[image]

This is my `/etc/config/dropbear` file:

[image]

VirutalBox Version 5.2.4 r119785 (Qt5.6.2

Comment: Can you run dropbear from console in the foreground to see what any errors it might spit out?

Answer (score 0):

The default config for dropbear does not allow for SSH with password from the WAN interface.

From the output above it looks like you're using virtualbox NAT interface so this is expected.

look in `/etc/config/dropbear` on the router to confirm and change the default settings

```
config dropbear
        option PasswordAuth 'on'
        option Port '22'
        option Interface 'lan'

config dropbear
        **option PasswordAuth 'off'**
        option Interface 'wan'
        option Port '2022'
```

also verify

option RootPasswordAuth 'on'
option RootLogin 'on'

if necessary, or at least the exclusion of

option RootPasswordAuth 'off'
option RootLogin 'off'

these options default to true

Comment: OK I added `/etc/config/dropbear` to the question. I added the lines for `RootLogin` and `Interface` to the file and rebooted. It's still not working. I tried `Interface 'lan'` and also `Interface 'eth0'`. https://postimg.org/image/ortd59b99/

Comment: it wouldn't be interface lan, as the lan in the case of openwrt, would be the interfaces that are clients to it. it would be wan.  or in the case of eth0, which interface on the openwrt host has the ip address 192.168.1.1? is it eth0?  it's not clear